# Проблема с асинхронностью, функции не вызываются одновременно

Tags: python, asyncio

Я написал программу на python, с использованием asyncio

```
import asyncio

async def update_heroes_list():
    # реализация функции update_heroes_list
    pass

async def update_heroes_win_rates():
    # реализация функции update_heroes_win_rates
    pass

async def update_counters():
    # реализация функции update_counters
    pass

async def find_pro_players():
    # реализация функции find_pro_players
    pass

async def find_players_win_rate():
    # реализация функции find_players_win_rate
    pass

async def main():
    tasks = [
        update_heroes_list(),
        update_heroes_win_rates(),
        update_counters(),
        find_pro_players(),
        find_players_win_rate()
    ]

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

вот примерное описание программы, мне нужно чтобы все 5 функций запускались одновременно, но они запускаются по очереди. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Видимо вы путаете асинхронность с параллельностью.

Comment: Для того чтобы ответить на вопрос нужно понять что происходит в этих функциях. Асинхронность поможет, если в них есть обращения к какому-то ресурсу. Например к БД. Причем обращение должно быть тоже асинхронно. Есть такое?

Comment: Они и не должны (физически не могут) запускаться одновременно. Даже параллельность не даст вам одновременный запуск. При асинхронности функции просто могут выполняться, пока другие функции ожидают что-то в await. Если у вас в функциях синхронный код без единого await, асинхронности тоже не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Асинхронность режет асинхронную функцию по слову `await` и исполняет кусочки по очереди или ждёт асинхронного доступа (сокета, таймера, файла, пайпа).

Тяжелый синхронный код блокирует исполнение других тасков.